# Isn't this function for grid.arrange correct?

Tags: r, r-grid

```
grid.arrange(hist1, hist2, nrow = 2)
```

This is the line of code with error

The error shown is -------------------------------------

```
Error in grid.arrange(hist1, hist2, nrow = 2) : 
  could not find function "grid.arrange
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a function of the gridExtra package. Make sure to include both

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
```

in your program!